# Unix Directory Issue

Tags: shell, unix, grep, cat

I have multiple folders like,

```
Folder_1
     sub_folder_1----->1.txt,2.txt,3.txt
     sub_folder_2----->2.txt,5,txt,6.txt
     sub_folder_3----->1.txt,2.txt,3.txt
     sub_folder_4----->1.txt,2.txt,3.txt
     sub_folder_5----->1.txt,2.txt,3.txt


Folder_2
     sub_folder_1----->1.txt,2.txt,3.txt
     sub_folder_2----->1.txt,2.txt,3.txt
     sub_folder_3----->1.txt,2.txt,3.txt
     sub_folder_4----->1.txt,2.txt,3.txt
     sub_folder_5----->1.txt,2.txt,3.txt

..........
```

Each `sub_folders_*` has so many `files(.txt)`inside it and I need to `cat` and combine all the files from all the `sub_folders` into `one unique file`.

I tried using `find /home/Arun/Labs/Master -maxdepth 2 -type f -exec cat {} \;`

But couldn't achieve it.

Any suggestions on how to do this Please ?

Comment: is there a pattern (naming convention) for your `folder_x` and `sub_folder_y` that you need to look for? or are you simply trying to "walk" all the folders recursively to produce a unique file ?

Comment: Yes @srj ! Naming convention of my folders will be exit-list-someyear-somenumber & that folder will contain the sub folders with folder name as (/01  /02  /03 ....... ) and that each folders will have so many files.

Comment: What is the problem with your `find` command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cat Folder_*/*/*.txt > new_file.txt
```

If you don't know how deep your directory tree is:

```
shopt -s globstar
cat **/*.txt > new_file.txt
```

---

From `man bash`:

> `globstar`: If  set,  the pattern ** used in a pathname expansion context will match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories.  If the pattern is followed by a /, only directories and subdirectories match.

Comment: Thank you so much ! Works pretty much great ! but loads of time to render  as my file repo is too large !

Answer (score 1):

If there is no complex structure involved in the folders, you could simply use a shell script with 2 `for` loops to achieve this

Assumptions: the structure is exactly the same as given in the question, with only directories in the first level, and all data in .txt files

```
#read_recursive.sh
for foldr in *
    do
      cd foldr
      for subf in *
      do
        cat *.txt
      done
      cd ..
    done

$ sh read_recursive.sh | uniq > final_output.txt
```

Comment: No, [don't parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) and it's [useless](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#ls) here anyway.

Comment: @tripleee, thanks for the info, changed the code to use globs instead, arun, you will need to exit the directory you CD'ed into, changed that as well

Comment: This will still be wrong if one of the directories is a symlink to a directory whose true parent directory is somewhere else, or (less crucially, but annoyingly) if a glob expands to something other than a directory.

Answer (score 1):

This `find` with `xargs` should handle that:

```
find /home/Arun/Labs/Master -maxdepth 2 -name '*.txt' -print0 | xargs -0 cat > /tmp/output.txt
```